# Power Failure while Partitioning

Tags: gparted, data-loss

I was running GParted in an Ubuntu Live instance to re-partition my hard drive. I had it set to shrink sda3, remove sda2, and enlarge sda6 which was in an extended partition. I accidentally forgot to plug the laptop in, so it died in the middle of the process. Now, I cannot access any of the files inside of it. When I try booting the partition, Grub2 runs, then the laptop goes back to the BIOS screen. When I try accessing the files using Nautilus, I get this error.

```
Unable to access “414 GB Volume”
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/trenta/ffda09dd-056e-4f64-8067-e37da22ce1da: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda6" "/media/trenta/ffda09dd-056e-4f64-8067-e37da22ce1da"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

GParted now shows this:
[image: Gparted view]

Any way I can get it to boot, or at least retrieve a file from that partition?

**UPDATE 1:**
To MGodby's comment, Here is the output of your recommendations. 
[image: terminal output]
When I ran `sudo fsck /dev/sda6` it said `Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).`. I was asked if I want to clear it, but wasn't sure what that would do, so I cancelled it. Should I clear it? Would that make my data irrecoverable?

Comment: Have you tried running the mount without the `-o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid"` in there? Also, have you tried running `sudo fsck /dev/sda6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently done something very similar. I erased the MBR of my hard disk. (Dont ask !!). Anyway, it was very easy to recover the lost partitions using a tool called testdisk.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Run testdisk from the command line. I'm not in front of my main PC right now so I can't run it and give you exact instructions but I am sure a quick duckduckgo about will help you out in that regard.

In essence, you select the hard disk, analyse it, search for partitions, select the partition from the list and view the files (make sure they are what you expect), then write the new MBR.

Your using Gparted so you sound pretty clued up on linux, I am sure testdisk will be no challange for you.

Good luck !

Comment: Using TestDisk I was able to recover lots of the files in that partition.